# Unable to parse JSON from GET request

Tags: c#, json, linq, deserialization

I'm attempting to integrate the Wikimedia API into a program I'm creating, but I've had trouble parsing out the content I wanted from the JSON it returns upon the GET request. This is the JSON the GET request returns:

```
{
  "batchcomplete": "",
  "query": {
    "normalized": [
      {
        "from": "program",
        "to": "Program"
      }
    ],
    "pages": {
      "23771": {
        "pageid": 23771,
        "ns": 0,
        "title": "Program",
        "revisions": [
          {
            "contentformat": "text/x-wiki",
            "contentmodel": "wikitext",
            "*": "the page content is too long to reasonably post here"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

All I want is the `title` and `*` values in a string or array or generic, anything that I can easily output back to the console window for reading, but given that the `Revisions` is placed under the page *number*, it can't be easily deserialized. I've tried LINQ but I don't understand it enough to construct a proper query.

Comment: Why not to use regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind an extra dependency, [JSON.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) does this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication10
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string str = @"{
  ""batchcomplete"": """",
  ""query"": {
    ""normalized"": [
      {
        ""from"": ""program"",
        ""to"": ""Program""
      }
    ],
    ""pages"": {
      ""23771"": {
        ""pageid"": 23771,
        ""ns"": 0,
        ""title"": ""Program"",
        ""revisions"": [
          {
            ""contentformat"": ""text/x-wiki"",
            ""contentmodel"": ""wikitext"",
            ""*"": ""the page content is too long to reasonably post here""
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}";
            var json = JObject.Parse(str);
            var pages = json["query"]["pages"].Values().First();

            Console.WriteLine(pages["title"]);
            Console.WriteLine(pages["revisions"][0]["*"]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I didn't see that solution. I feel so incredibly foolish. Thank you very much, I'll mark this as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [json.net](/questions/tagged/json.net) for this purpose.  It parses JSON to c# classes and also supports direct Linq queries of json using its [Linq to JSON](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm)

You don't include your attempted c# classes, however the "pages" object can be deserialized as a dictionary, for instance:

```
public class Query
{
    // Property for "normalized" if needed.
    public Dictionary<string, Page> pages { get; set; }
}
```

See [Serialize a Dictionary](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/serializedictionary.htm).

As for a LINQ query, you can parse your JSON string to [`JToken`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ParsingLINQtoJSON.htm) then use [`JToken.SelectTokens()`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenWithLinq.htm).  This method supports querying JSON objects using [JSONPath query syntax](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenJsonPath.htm) which includes wildcards:

```
        var root = JToken.Parse(jsonString);

        var pages = root.SelectTokens("query.pages.*").ToList();
        var titles = pages.Select(p => (string)p.SelectToken("title")).ToList();
        var revisions = pages.Select(p => p.SelectTokens("revisions[*]['*']").Select(s => (string)s)).ToList();
```

JSONPath query syntax is described here: [JSONPath - XPath for JSON](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/).